# Informix HDR implementation on Windows 2012 R2 server

Tags: informix, database-administration

We are implementing HDR (High Availability Data Replication) on Windows 2012 R2 Server.

Steps done:

1) Two new Windows 2012 R2 Servers.

IDS 12.10FC8 installed and created the instance manually using Server Instance 
Manager.

**Server A** details:

```
DBSERVERNAME: hdr_primary
Host Name: winhdr
IP Address: 199.166.155.195
Port Number: 50005
```

**Server B details**:

```
DBSERVERNAME: hdr_secondary
Host Name: winhdr2
IP Address: 199.166.155.196
Port Number: 50005
```

2) We have only one instance with one database in Server A (Primary). 
No database in Server B (Secondary).

3) We have made changes required for HDR in ONCONFIG, Sqlhosts file on both server.

**ONCONFIG parameters Server A:**

```
DBSERVERNAME hdr_primary
ROOTPATH C:\IFMXDATA\hdr_primary\rootdbs_dat.000
ROOTSIZE 204800
DRAUTO 0
DRINTERVAL 0
HDR_TXN_SCOPE FULL_SYNC
DRTIMEOUT 30
```

**ONCONFIG parameters Server B:**

```
DBSERVERNAME hdr_primary
ROOTPATH C:\IFMXDATA\hdr_primary\rootdbs_dat.000
ROOTSIZE 204800
DRAUTO 0
DRINTERVAL 0
HDR_TXN_SCOPE FULL_SYNC
DRTIMEOUT 30
```

**SQL hosts** at both servers: placed in `%INFORMIXDIR%\etc`

```
hdr_secondary onsoctcp winhdr2 hdrsecport
hdr_primary onsoctcp winhdr hdrpriport
```

**host file** at both servers: placed in `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc`

```
199.166.155.195 winhdr
199.166.155.196 winhdr2

winhdr 199.166.155.195
winhdr2 199.166.155.196
```

**host.equvi** file @ both servers: placed in `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc`

```
winhdr informix
winhdr2 informix
```

**services** file @ both servers: placed in `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc`

```
hdrpriport 50005/tcp #hdr_primary
hdrsecport 50005/tcp #hdr_secondary
```

4) After all configuration setting has done we have take ontape backup at 
Server A.

Server A status: On-Line

```
ontape -s -L 0
```

5) Moved the L0 backup to server B and restored with ontape. Cold restore.

`ontape -p`

Server B status: Fast Recovery

6) On Server A we had run the below command:

```
onmode -d primary hdr_secondary
```

Server A status: On-Line(Prim)

7) On Server B we had run the below command:

```
onmode -d secondary hdr_primary**
```

Server B status: Fast Recovery(sec).

Till here we have done.

From here we are facing an issue.

The output at server B of `onstat -g dri`:

```
Data Replication at 0000000080CEC030: 

Type---------------State--------    Paired server -----------Last DR CKPT (id/pg) 
Supports Proxy Writes 

    HDR Secondary  off      hdr_primary          -1 / -1 N

DRINTERVAL 0 
DRTIMEOUT 30 
DRAUTO 0 
DRLOSTFOUND C:\PROGRA~1\IBMINF~1\etc\dr.lostfound 
DRIDXAUTO 1 
ENCRYPT_HDR 0 
Backlog 0 
Nothing Sent 
Nothing Received 
No Pings 
Last log page applied(log id,page): 0,0

Issue: Primary and Secondary are not Paired.
```

Error in Online log is: 
Server A

```
DR: Trying to connect to secondary server = hdr_secondary 

DR: Cannot connect to secondary server 

DR: Turned off on primary server
```

Server B

```
DR: Trying to connect to primary server = hdr_primary 

DR: Cannot connect to primary server 

DR: Turned off on secondary server
```

Comment: Hi. I want you to be able to get the help you need, so I edited your post to try to make it as clear as possible. You should probably review it to see if you can make your question any clearer or narrower. Also, please see [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326569/under-what-circumstances-may-i-add-urgent-or-other-similar-phrases-to-my-quest).

Comment: Better suited on [sf]

Answer (score 0):

A good practice to test communication between the two servers, is opening dbaccess -> connect -> and choose the remote server alias.

If you cannot connect through dbaccess, you have a network/communication issue that must be investigated. Open a PMR with IBM support.

Make sure your UPDATABLE_SECONDARY onconfig is set to 0, if you don't have licensed your secondary instance as a read/write, just in case.